# JAWS - Submitted form in iframe reads source URL even though there is a title

Tags: html, drupal, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I'm developing a form that is displayed in an iframe. When the form is first displayed (on click) I add a title to the iframe, and JAWS reads everything nicely.

When the form is submitted with errors, JAWS reads everything I expect it to, but it also reads out the URL of the iframe, which is very long.

On initial display, JAWS reads this:

> {Page title} dialog
>
> {Page title} frame
>
> {first link inside frame}

When the form is submitted with an error, JAWS reads this:

> {Page title} dialog
>
> {Page title} frame
>
> {Page title} read only
>
> {long URL of iframe}
>
> {first link inside frame}

Can anyone help me figure out these questions:

- What does "read only" mean in this context?
- How can I prevent the long URL being read?

Thanks

Comment: What version of JAWS are you using? And in what browser? And since you say "submitted with errors" I assume you're doing server-side validation? It sounds as if JAWS can't find a name for your frame source. I'm not sure why that would be - JAWS 12 and 13 work pretty hard to find a name, either from the <title> element of the source file, the title attribute of the <iframe> element in the host file, or as a last resort the src filename (without path or extension). Absent of that it may announce the long URL and state. The state exposed by MSAA for all non-editable elements is "read only"

Comment: Thanks - this is with JAWS 12 - definitely in Firefox, and I think also in IE and Chrome.

Yes, validation is happening server-side - the form itself is a Drupal webform, using the webform_validation module.

Comment: @malcomio did you manage to fix this issue?